# Setting up VPN tunnel: what are the possible ways by which my true IP address could leak?

Tags: vpn, ip, data-leakage, infoleak

I bought a subscription to a VPN service and I set up the VPN tunnel using openvpn.

In order to avoid DNS leaks, I am using the DNS servers provided by my VPN provider by manually enforcing /etc/resolv.conf.

By navigating on the internet, what are all the possible ways by which my real IP address could leak?
(I mean involuntary ways that don't involve downloading and running an executable with root privileges, but Javascript is in scope for this question).

For instance, the ExpressVPN client has a protection against WebRTC IP leaks, and you can check whether you are exposed [here](https://www.expressvpn.com/webrtc-leak-test).

What are all the other possible ways through which the real IP address could leak? Javascript? Java? Flash? Other web technologies?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Yes it does. Thanks